Scaling up Text view in SwiftUI
I'm having image overlayed with text which I want to export as an image scaled up to image's dimensions. The thing I'm struggling with is how to scale up the Text view. If I calculate the scale factor (imageSize.width/previewViewSize.width) and multiply font size with it'd work but it's not precise enough - sometimes it would make line breaks difference between preview and export.
I've also tried setting .frame modifier of Text with scale factor applied when exporting, and to make the text grow I first set .font to some maximum size and than .minimumScaleFactor to some small value like 0.001 but that's even more imprecise.
Here's the code I tried with preview screenshot, this is solution is scaling up the font with scale factor:
struct TextOverlayView: View {

  let scale: CGFloat
  @State var textViewSize: CGSize = .zero

  init(scale: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    self.scale = scale
  }

  var body: some View {
    Image(uiImage: testImage)
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        Text(
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
        )
        .font(.system(size: 18 * scale))
        .bold()
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
      }
  }

  @MainActor
  func generateImage() -> UIImage? {
    var image: UIImage?

    let renderer = ImageRenderer(
      content:
        self
    )

    image = renderer.uiImage

    return image
  }
}

#Preview {

  let textViewPreview = TextOverlayView()
  let textViewExport = TextOverlayView(scale: textViewPreview.testImage.size.width / 393) // 393 - width of the preview view

  let generatedImage = textViewExport.generateImage()

  let resultAndExportViews = VStack {
    textViewPreview

    Image(uiImage: generatedImage!)
      .resizable()
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
  }

  return resultAndExportViews
}


